# ANOVA variable that is both BETWEEN & WITHIN

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, spss, experiment-design

Does anyone know how / if can you treat an independent variable as BOTH a between AND within subjects variable (ideally in SPSS ANOVA-repeated measures).  That is, we have a repeated measures study where the independent variable is DEVICE (6 levels).  The catch is, each respondent will only be exposed to 3 devices and we want to do the analysis across all 6.  We will taking 3 measures for each device.

Comment: Isn't this a nested (hierarchical) analysis of variance?

Comment: This calls for a multilevel model. If you are using SPSS check out the MIXED procedure.